# How can i extend mongoose Query with typescript?

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose

I'm trying to adapt this piece of code to typescript: https://github.com/kephin/Node_Redis-Caching/blob/master/services/cache.js
, but I'm not able to extend the  Query object.

Currently in extending it with declaration merging the same way I'm doing with express, but in this case it doesn't work

```js
declare namespace Mongoose {
  interface Query {
    cache: any;
  }
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to extend it?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work.https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/bqftwc/im_having_a_hard_time_moving_a_piece_of_code_to/

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it working like this:

```
# mongoose.d.ts

type CacheOptions = { key?: string }

declare module 'mongoose' {
  interface DocumentQuery<T, DocType> {
    cache(options?: CacheOptions): Query<T>
    useCache: boolean
    hashKey: string
  }
}
```